# Cocos2d : how can increase my sprite's position.x every time I create it

Tags: xcode, animation, cocos2d-iphone, position, sprite

well I create a sprite every second at the same position . And I would like to create the sprite but every time with x + 10 .So every second the sprite is created but with an x position that grows of 10. sorry for my english, I french :/

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a static variable you increment each time you create a sprite:

```
 static int x = 0;
 create_sprite(x, 0);
 x += 10;
```

I'm not familiar with cocoas2d's actual syntax, but that should work.

Comment: Why static? a class attribute is enough.

Comment: @EfEs: It is, you're right. We answered at the same time, me using a static, you using a class attribute. I just wanted to give the simplest thing I could think of, I didn't want to assume he's using classes.

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode for cpp cocos2d-x, mind me.

header:

```
class Myclass extends CCScene{

    public int position = 0;
    ...
}
```

MyClass.cpp:

```
Myclass(){
    ...
    CCDirector::getSharedDirector()->schedule(step, 1/60);
}


void step() {
    ...
    if (oneSecond()){
        position += 10;
        createSprite(position);
    }
    ...
}
```